# Prove that the function has a maximum value

Tags: calculus

$f(x) : [0, +\infty)$  is continuous and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = A,f(0) >A$. I need to prove that $f$ has a maximum value.It's not hard to prove that $f$ is bounded, but i just can't seem find a way to use the last condition in any resourceful way.

Comment: When $x$ becomes large, $f(x)$ will be less than $f(0)$. If $f$ has maximum, it must be in some interval like $[0, K]$ for large $K$. Then you should know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=A, f(0)>A$. Thus there's a $x_0\in [0,\infty)$ so that for all $x>x_0$ we have
$$f(x)<f(0).$$
The continous function $f$ attains a maximum on the compact interval $[0,x_0]$. By definition of $x_0$ is clear that this is the maximum we looked for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, credit should go to @sigmabe, and a more detailed answer would be: $A =\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)\Rightarrow $ For $\epsilon = f(0) - A > 0$, there is a large number $N > 0$ such that if $x > N \Rightarrow |f(x)-A| < \epsilon\Rightarrow f(x) < \epsilon+A=f(0)$. Thus $f(x) < f(0), x > N$, and on the closed interval $[0,N]$, $f$ is continuous, hence attains a maximum there, and this maximum is also the global maximum of $f$ over $[0,\infty)$.